# Integral equation with a function limit

Tags: integration

I am doing a research paper and I faced with this problem. Does anyone know the answer (or an approximation for the answer) for the following
integral equation?
$$\int_0^{y(x)} e^{-xt}f(t)dt = g(x)$$
We want to find $y(x)$. In case it  is necessary, we know that  $y(0)=0$ and $g(0)=0$. We know that $f(x)$ is a probability density function and $\int_0^\infty$f(x)dx=1.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating with respect to $x$ (if $g$ is regular enough)?

Comment: yes, but it did not end up with a closed form answer. May be I did not do it properly.

Comment: Closed form is out of the question in this generality. You're dealing with integration and inverting a function as subproblems, which already don't have explicit answers. Existence of a solution isn't guaranteed either.

Comment: Even a clue of how we can come up with a solution (even if it is not in a closed form) is important for me.

Comment: @Mamal Define the word "solution".

Comment: Since $f \ge 0$,  existence of a solution is guaranteed if $g(x) < \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} f(t)\; dt$, while if $g(x) > \int_0^\infty e^{-xt} f(t)\; dt$ there is no solution.